# How did Hap manage to cross borders with kidnapped victims?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-oa

In *The OA* S01E05, how did Hap and Homer fly/travel out of the US and into Cuba? And then later back to the US with an additional prisoner, Renata?

Entering the US with two unwilling prisoners, one of whom has been missing for years, seems absurdly implausible, even if one has a small private plane.

Comment: DIRECT flights were banned, flying via somewhere else was possible.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Going to Cuba is not the big deal. The big deal is entering the US with two unwilling prisoners, one of whom has been missing for years.